# What is the best practice to assign a class to an HTML element based on a back end variable using flask and JINJA?

Tags: python, html, flask, coding-style, jinja2

Suppose that I have a variable passed into a JINJA template that determines the class of an HTML element. I have found two methods that work but both seem to have their cons

1. JINJA if clauses within HTML body. However, this tends to obscure the code and loses readability.
2. JINJA if clauses within javascript and add the class using JS. This keeps the code clean but relevant code pieces are scattered around.

I would appreciate other options too. I came up with setting up the class variables in the flask processing end and passing it directly via JINJA but I guess that is not the role of a back end system and hence should not be put in place.
Sorry for the trivial question but I could not find any directions regarding this.